# slide Wipe effects with ImageMagick tool and ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, imagemagick, composite

I have to do a four slide effects named 'Wipe Up', 'Wipe Down', 'Wipe Right', 'Wipe Left'. Like curtain of two images for each type. I think it can be possible with cropping of images with 'convert'

```
convert 01.jpg -crop 1920x5 output_%03d.jpg
```

where i can get sequence of images and compose at same time to the second image(What I don't know..) And then I can build video from this sequence of images with ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i output_%03d.jpg out.mp4
```

Maybe someone can help me with compossing of images in the same time when I croping? Thanks for any suggestions!

PS: all images have fixed dimensions: 1920x1080

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use ImageMagick's `MIFF` format (Multiple Image File Format) to send a stream of multiple, cropped images to another invocation of ImageMagick to put them together in a video sequence. So assuming you start with this:

[image]

and did this

```
convert input.png -crop 1920x10 miff:- | convert - -loop 0 out.gif
```

you would get this

[image]

Comment: It was really helpful, thank you, but how can I compose it with second image and get sequence of images?

Comment: I don't understand what you want, sorry. Can you explain or show an example please?

Comment: I haven't properly examples, but on this page there is some .. http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/transitions named "Wipe" and first of them

Comment: It's like in your example, but with another image on background, and will be better to get a sequense of images with this transition to build a video  with ffmpeg then.

Comment: Found an example [link](https://youtu.be/_G8JVMKKZXk) , but with videos, I try to do the same but with images input, and then build a video;
[Left Wipe Example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xdq0C5valao)