# Wipe image in and out with ffmpeg / imagemagick

Tags: animation, video, ffmpeg, imagemagick, transition

I'd like to create a wipe in/out from left to right effect with `ffmpeg` and/or `ImageMagick` that is common to most video editors. (e.g. Adobe Premiere, Final Cut Pro and even OpenShot) Some might call this a slide in/out transition effect.

I found that ffmpeg has a lot of [filters](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html) (including fades), but none seem to be the correct choice for this.

There are also ImageMagick transitions that achieve a wipe in effect. Like in the following example (that is derived from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29525915/slide-wipe-effects-with-imagemagick-tool-and-ffmpeg)):

```
convert overlay.png -crop 10x1080 miff:- | convert - out.gif
```

But I found it hard to control the actual speed/duration of the transition. I'd like it to last only 2.5 seconds. But I can't make it that fast, because the `-delay 1x30` option doesn't seem to let me decrease the delay that low. There is also a library with ImageMagick transitions [here](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/transitions/) that unfortuantely isn't compatible with `batch`.

I suppose there is a solution for `ffmpeg` that I couldn't think of, yet. I'd really appreciate your advice!

Comment: What unit is 1/30? Is that 1/30 sec or ticks. Most viewers only allow a minimum delay that may vary with viewers. So if you specify too small a value, it will not be used. You seem to have specified a value that is too small. In imagemagick delays are in ticks (nominally 1/100th sec). So a delay of 30 ticks would be 0.3 sec. Also you cannot specify ratios or fractions, but you can change the ticks per second. Nevertheless, the viewers may specify a minimum value that is larger than your specified delay.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I meant 1x30 :) Anyway, I‘d prefer a ffmpeg Solution if possible, because even if I speed up via ImageMagick the animation will appear laggy. Also I have problems importing transparent, animated gifs as an overlay via ffmpeg (black background and no animation, even if exported as mp4). Thanks for your hint!